# Как автоматически выполнить батник в командной строке?

Tags: bat, cmd

Задача - выкинуть всех пользователей из терминала, ежедневно в назначенное время. Win2003srv. Как я это планировал сделать:

1. Написать батник
2. Запихать в назначенные задания.

Обломало меня то, что при запуске батника открывается cmd.exe, где в бесконечном цикле отображается сама команда из батника. При запуске батника непосредственно из cmd.exe всё работает как надо. Вот код батничка:

```
echo Y| logoff 65536
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: какое имя файла(батника)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset session Позволяет сбросить (удалить) сеансы с сервера терминалов.

Синтаксис

```
reset session {имя_сеанса|код_сеанса} [/server:имя_сервера] [/v]
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил свой вопрос таким образом:   echo Y| reset session rdp-tcp

Answer (score 1):

Использовать команду:

```
start cmd /c
```

Вообще откуда может быть бесконечный цикл, если в батнике указана только это строка? Может быть батник бесконечно вызывается и копать нужно в сторону задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Мне почему-то кажется, что батник называется **`logoff.bat`**, это объясняет цикличность, переименуйте, например, в **`mylogoff.bat`**.

Comment: ArcherGodson, вы экстрасенс. К сожалению не могу плюсануть.

Comment: я знаю, вашей благодарности вполне достаточно ))

Answer (score 1):

rwinsta #сессии /server:SERVERNAMEНапример: rwinsta 1 /server:HOME-1rwinsta 2 /server:HOME-1

и повторить эту команду в батнике столько раз, сколько возможных сессий открыто.

Потом батник поставить в sheduler на определенное время.

P.S. все вышенаписанное справедливо для Win Server 2k3, 2k8/r2. Работоспособность в Server 2000 не проверял.Запускается только под админом.

- ко всему. Вообще, w2k3 позволяет выкидывать неактивные сессии автоматически, после некоторого указанного времени. Это делается в профилях пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

А под каким пользователем выполняется батник в задаче? Запуск должен происходить от имени пользователя с достаточными (т.е. административными) правами.